Redirect to "add new product" once finished publishing a new product (skip edit page) - code not working
As the title suggests, I'd like to completely skip the "edit" page once I add a new product, and go directly to adding a new product instead. The time it takes my cart to switch pages is just horrible, this will greatly speed up my process of adding thousands of products.
I am aware that ChatGPT isn't always the best route to go when looking for coding help, but it did suggest some code for me to add to functions.php, however, it's not working. When I finish publishing a new product, it's still returning me to the edit product page. Any idea why this might not be working?
Code:
add_action('save_post_product', 'redirect_to_add_new_product', 20, 2);

function redirect_to_add_new_product($post_id, $post) {
    // Check if it's a new product and not an autosave
    if ($post->post_status === 'publish' && defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && !DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        // Remove the custom meta to prevent redirect loop
        delete_post_meta($post_id, '_is_new_product');
        
        // Redirect to the "Add New Product" page
        wp_redirect(admin_url('post-new.php?post_type=product'));
        exit;
    }
}

add_action('load-post-new.php', 'set_new_product_meta');

function set_new_product_meta() {
    // Check if it's a new product being created
    if (isset($_GET['post_type']) && $_GET['post_type'] === 'product') {
        $screen = get_current_screen();
        if ($screen->id === 'post') {
            add_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_is_new_product', true);
        }
    }
}

Added code to functions.php
Added a new product and clicked publish.
Expected the page to then return to add a new product, but instead, it is still returning to the edit product page where I have to click on "add new product".
